# In R, how to make dots transparent while using scale_size in ggplot2?

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, visualization, ggmap

This equation leads from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302195/plotting-google-map-with-ggplot-in-r). I want to plot dots that represent total population and so far I used `scale_size` to make dots' size relative to its total population.

But, I want to make these dots transparent because the dots are covering the map. I am, however, open to other options as long as the message I am trying to send is clear.
[image]

```
# load required packages
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

# query map of Birmingham, AL
al1 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -86.304474, lat = 32.362563), zoom = 11,
       source = "osm", maptype = 'terrain')

al1MAP <- ggmap(al1)+ geom_point(data=quote_bmh, 
          aes(x=IntPtLon, y=IntPtLat, size=TotPop, colour="gold2"),
          colour="gold2") + scale_size(range=c(0,15))
```

Comment: An alternative can be to interpolate the population points using e.g. inverse distance weighted interpolation (`idw` in `gstat`), kriging (e.g. `automap`), or some kernel method (i.e. 2d density).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use a uniform transparency, just add `alpha = 0.3` to `geom_point`. `alpha` can be between 0 and 1, depending on the amount of transparency you want. If you want to make you transparency depend on a variable, just add `alpha = var_name` to the `mapping` argument (the `aes` bit), where `var_name` is the column name of the variable you want to use for transparency.

Comment: Dang that Paul is quick, saw it and went to post and bam he's answered.  +1

Comment: Hahah, I first typed the first part of the answer, than edited to add more detail. These kinds of questions are answered far too quickly, so I needed to be fast :).

Comment: Wow, you answered so fast that I have to wait ten min to accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great I could help :), good way to spend some time waiting for the EGU poster session to begin :)

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to use hollow points, e.g. `geom_point(shape = 21)`.  That would make the map directly under the point quite readable while making the edges of the points distinctly visible.

(Unfortunately, my employer blocks the Google API, so I can't post the result)