# How we can colorize data using a similar color scheme to that used on google's maps?

Tags: r, plot

I have got a file which represents the vegetation cover and would like to plot it.I did plot it (you can see it below)but the colour was not helpful. values in my file go from 0 to 7(not only 7 values). I would like the colour to be almost like the map of Google which is attached(link).

to read the file:

```
       dat=file("D:\\dat.img","rb")
       dat<- readBin(dat, integer(), size=1,  n=1440*720, signed=F)
       dat <- raster(t(matrix((data=dat), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))
        plot(dat, col = rev(terrain.colors(30)))
```

Comment: Are you trying to reproduce the google map using your data, do you just want to colorize your data using a similar color scheme to that used on google's maps, or are you trying to overlay your data on a google map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use `ggmap` package , to plot google maps as a background.

```
library(ggmap)
center <- geocode('ile-de-France')
map <- get_map(location=c(center$lon,center$lat),
               maptype = 'terrain',
               zoom=12)
ggmap(map)
```

[image]

Comment: They're not looking for satellite tiles. Check the link. I'd edit your code since your solution probably still applies, but I don't really know my way around this package. EDIT: figured it out: you want "terrain" tiles, not "satellite."

Comment: @sacvf 1. set `location = c(0,0)` to center the map, `zoom=2` to zoom out. This gives you most of the globe, but it's a little cut off on the edges. 2. ggplot graphics are based on layers, so there should be an easy way to add a layer for your data to the plot. It would be easier if you could provide a reproducible data sample.

Comment: @DavidMarx thanks for your help. even `terrain` don't look the same? isn't it? I am not specialist I just get the idea to use ggmap as a layer

Comment: @sacvf you should give data to get better answers. your map disappers it is normal. The idea is to use map produced by ggmap  as a first layer , than use your data to plot what you wwant.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to customize using the RColorBrewer package. There is more on http://www.packtpub.com/article/adjusting-key-parameters-r

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources that could be used to expand the answer provided.

This paper has some resources regarding ggmap.
http://stat405.had.co.nz/ggmap.pdf

Here is a SO question:
[Plotting google map with ggplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302195/plotting-google-map-with-ggplot-in-r)

An easy to follow example:
http://uchicagoconsulting.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/how-to-draw-good-looking-maps-in-r/

Using spplot(). For some things easier than ggplot2 or ggmap
http://geography.uoregon.edu/GeogR/examples/maps_examples02.htm

Here you can find political boundaries of many countries. They have them in shapefiles and R files.
http://www.gadm.org/country